# remove that special characters and unwanted numbers in cognos report studio

Tags: cognos-10

I have a description field with special characters and unwanted number, I want to remove that special characters and unwanted numbers which is **BOLD** in the example description in report studio report.

Description Field:-
**31-** Customer Reference Number: 2388094412 **~32-** BUYER NAME OR DEPARTMENT:F13 **-~33-** DELIVERY REQUESTED ON 06/01/11 **~34-** CANCEL AFTER 06/16/15 ~35-ATTENTION ELAINE HOWIE~36- CANCEL ALL BACKORDERS. CHECK COSTS ******||** BEFORE SHIPPING  **~37-**  FAX 43575 8795  **~10-** CALL FOR APPT: 450/642-0101.  **~30-**GST/HST #10574 8278 RT0001**##~**

Note:- We don’t know how many special characters , unwanted numbers and specific length of characters.
Cognos :-10.2.2 version
Database :- Oracle
Relational database

Thanks
RK

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to define special characters to remove, I'd simply create a regular expression that defined the legal characters I'd want to include. Since you are using Oracle as your data source you can use the REGEXP_REPLACE Oracle native function to replace the characters that aren't in a specified list with an empty string.

Example:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(description,'[^A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&*]','')
```

This would return the string with anything that wasn't a letter, number or specified punctuation removed. In practice you'd want to expand the list of punctuation to include more characters such as period and comma but I think this illustrates the concept.

Comment: Thanks Johns, I will try with that function and will let you know